# Execute java file and get output from cmd

Tags: java

I want to compile second file and get the output but it throw an Exception .

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String path="C:\\Users\\Amr\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Second.java";   

    Process pro1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac " + path);

    ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder("java ", path);

    ps.redirectErrorStream(true);

    Process pr = ps.start();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    pr.waitFor();
    System.out.println("ok!");

    in.close();

    pro1.waitFor();

}
```

Get output from this class

```
public class Second {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world from Second.java");
}}
```

please any help for repairing the errors

that is the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Amr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Second.java
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? And why do you have two main methods?

Comment: In which class is the first main method located? Still wondering why you have two main methods.

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to load "Second.java" as a class file. Try replacing Second.java with Second.class

Comment: @jiaweizhang 
i want to get output Second class (external class not has a relation with another class ) from cmd

Comment: @Spencer4134
output the same exception

Comment: Ok type C:\Users\Amr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ in your file explorer and see if it really is in there. It could be in a subfolder

Comment: Yes , it is here 
http://postimg.org/image/57a3d8awn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder("java ", path);
```

You're executing `java Second.java` it should be `java Second`

replace `path.replace(".java","")` or create a variable without ".java"

```
nsaravanas@ubuntu:~$ pwd
/home/nsaravanas
nsaravanas@ubuntu:~$ javac com/test/Second.java
nsaravanas@ubuntu:~$ java com.test.Second
Hello world from Second.java
nsaravanas@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: do your class have package? I've edited my answer,could you check?